# calculate $\int_{|z|=2}\sqrt{z^2-1}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Given:

Calculate $\int_{|z|=2}\sqrt{z^2-1} dz$

Hint:$\sqrt{z^2-1}=z\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}:=z\exp(\frac{1}{2}\log(1-\frac{1}{z^2}))$

I tried it for several hours and didn't manage to get anywhere i would be happy to get another hint for solving this.

Edit:
I thought maybe using the formula $(1+z)^k=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{k(k-1)...(k-n+1)}{n!}z^n$
and i got to this after some calcualtions
$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z}{2}+\frac{1}{4z}+o(z^{-3})dz$

Comment: Can you describe what you tried?

Comment: to be honest i didn't even know where to start

Comment: Do you know the residues formula ?

Comment: I thought about it user but didn't see how to go with it and i don't know the residues formula

Comment: yes but i don't understand the proof of the writer there if you can help @user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hint leads to the Laurent expansion
$$\eqalign{\sqrt{z^2-1}&=z\left(1-{1\over z^2}\right)^{1/2}=z\left(1-{1\over2z^2}-{1\over8z^4}-{1\over16z^6}-\ldots\right)\cr
&=z-{1\over2z}-{1\over8z^3}-{1\over16z^5}-\ldots\qquad\bigl(|z|>1\bigr)\ ,\cr}
$$
which converges uniformly, e.g.,  on an annulus ${3\over2}\leq|z|\leq3$. Here I have developed $\left(1-{1\over z^2}\right)^{1/2}$ into a binomial series, using the standard formula
$$(1+t)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\alpha\choose k} t^k\qquad\bigl(|t|<1\bigr)\ .$$It is now easy to determine the value of the desired integral.

Comment: Hi professor Blatter, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682336/vq-le-sum-i-1k-vq-i-where-q-1-q-k-are-rectangles-that-cover-the-r)?

Comment: First thanks but for some reason i got the following expansion $z(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4z^2}+o(z^{-4}})$ instead

Comment: How did you calculate the radius for the series i've tried it but didn't get to the same radius

Comment: @ronkurman: The series converges for all $|z|>1$, but I needed a compact annulus where it converges uniformly. The choice I made is arbitrary.